# Do PHP functions exist across different PHP tags?

Tags: php, function

If I have a script like this:

```
<?php
    function myFunc(){
        return "some text";
    }
>
...some more html...
<?php
    echo myFunc();
>
```

Does the function declared in the first php block exist in the second php block?

Comment: Why won't you simply check that?

Comment: Yes of course. You also can easily test whether this is true or not. Why did you ask this?

Comment: Is it really so hard to try this? it's all of about 6 lines of code and 30 seconds to type it up and run it. But yes, function scope is global for a page, it's not per-block. If it was, PHP would be an utterly useless language.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it does. You can even require and/or include other files with function, class, interface, etc. definitions and access them in subsequent blocks.